# Typing Unicode symbols using WM_CHAR

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode

How can I type some Unicode symbols(like a cyrillic) using WM_CHAR message? Now I have uncorrect typing of cyrillic symbols.
This is my code:

```
DWORD dwCurrentTreadID = GetCurrentThreadId();
HWND hForeground = GetForegroundWindow();
DWORD dwForegroungThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hForeground, NULL);
AttachThreadInput(dwForegroungThreadID,dwCurrentTreadID,true);
PostMessageW(GetFocus(), WM_CHAR, character, 1);
```

Comment: Probably you don't. Probably you use automation rather than faking input.

Answer (score 1):

[You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/05/30/423202.aspx).  Use `SendInput()` instead:

```
INPUT input = {0};

input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
input.ki.wScan = (WORD) character;
input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;

SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

Unicode in Windows uses UTF-16.  `wScan` is 16-bit, so it can only hold individual UTF-16 codeunits.  You can fit Unicode codepoints up to `U+FFFF` into a single codeunit, but to send a codepoint higher than U+FFFF (which requires 2 codeunits) you have to supply 2 `INPUT` values, one for each codeunit:

```
INPUT input[2] = {0};
int numInput;

// character should be a 32bit codepoint and not exceed 0x10FFFF...
if (character <= 0xFFFF)
{
    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wScan = (WORD) character;
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;

    numInput = 1;
}
else
{
    character -= 0x010000;

    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[0].ki.wScan = (WORD) (((character >> 10) & 0x03FF) + 0xD800);
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;

    input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    input[1].ki.wScan = (WORD) ((character & 0x03FF) + 0xDC00);
    input[0].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;

    numInput = 2;
}

SendInput(numInput, input, sizeof(INPUT));
```

You could wrap this in a function that sends a UTF-16 encoded input string:

```
void SendInputStr(const std::wstring &str) // in C++11, use std::u16string instead...
{
    if (str.empty()) return;

    std::vector<INPUT> input(str.length());

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
    {
        input[i].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        input[i].ki.wScan = (WORD) str[i];
        input[i].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    }

    SendInput(input.size(), &input[0], sizeof(INPUT));
}
```